# Redirect using navigate() to the same URL updating the state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

**'/'URL Login handler function**

```
const loginHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        Services.login(email, password)
          .then((Res) => {
            if(Res.data==="success"){
              navigate('/home')
            }
            else {
              navigate('/',{
                state: {
                  msg: Res.data,
                }})
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      };
```

On **Res.data** other than **success** I want to redirect to the same **/Url** by updating the state of a component so that I can display proper error message on the same  page and prevent user to navigate to **/home Url** . How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it's not too useful to navigate to the same page as you intend. Seems more straightforward to keep some state on the current page and show/hide an error message based on that state

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ThisPage = () => {
    const [failed, setFailed] = useState(false);
    
    const loginHandler = () => {
        ....when you get to your error
        }else{
            setFailed(true);
        }
    }
    //then render an error message on this page if failed
    return(
        <div>
            <SomeOtherContent />
            <div hidden={!failed}>Something went wrong!</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

If you really need to navigate to the same page, you could look into using useContext() to keep a state that is outside of the page component so that it would still be there when you redirect to the same component (and rerender it).
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext